# auto reply whatsapp with python, flash and twilio

Tags: python, flask, twilio, bots, whatsapp

Hello anyone can help me.
I make machine learning with tensorflow as backend and I want to integrate that machine learning with whatsapp. I integrate it with twilio api and flask. But I have a problem when I run it there is an error.

this is my code

```
def chatbot_response(msg):
    ints = predict_class(msg, model)
    res = getResponse(ints, intents)
    return res


#Creating GUI with tkinter
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def bot():
        incoming_msg = request.values.get('Body', '').lower()
        resp = MessagingResponse()
        msg2= resp.message()
        print(request.values)
        msg=chatbot_response(incoming_msg)
        msg2.body(msg)
        return str(resp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
       app.run(debug=True)
```

and this is the error screenshot
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMekB.png)

Please anyone can help me, what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Can you check if your app crash before the messaging response or when ur msg is pass to the model ?

Comment: could you also include the code from the functions that are returning the errors?